SELECT duplicate values excluding most frequently used
I have two relevant tables in MySQL that look something like this:
marker table



id
SEASONCD
ITEMCD
PRICETYPECD




1
foo
bar
baz


2
foo
bar
baz


3
foo
bar
baz


4
qux
bar
baz


5
qux
bar
baz


6
spam
eggs
ham



seat_marker table



id
MARKER_ID




1
1


2
1


3
1


4
6



I would like to select all of the rows in the marker table that are duplicates, excluding the one that is most frequently referenced / joined by the seat_marker table. In other words, I would like to list all duplicates excluding the "original", where "original" is defined as the row with the most occurrences in seat_marker.MARKER_ID.
The result would look like this:



id
SEASONCD
ITEMCD
PRICETYPECD




2
foo
bar
baz


3
foo
bar
baz


5
qux
bar
baz



We can see this is the original data from the marker table, but with three rows removed;

id 1 was removed because it was the foo-bar-baz duplicate that occurred more frequently in seat_marker than the other foo-bar-baz rows.
id 4 was removed because it was a duplicate. Since the qux-bar-baz rows show up 0 times in seat_marker, I don't have a preference if we remove id 4 or id 5. I chose id 4 at random.
id 6 was removed because it is not a duplicate

The closest I've been able to get is this, which lists all values that are a duplicate and the number of assignments it has. But does not exclude the "originals".
-- Select all duplicates, and list the number of times it's referenced in the seat_marker table
SELECT 
  n1.id, n1.SEASONCD, n1.ITEMCD, n1.PRICETYPECD, (
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM seat_marker 
    WHERE MARKER_ID = n1.id
  ) active_assignments
FROM marker n1, marker n2 
WHERE
    n1.id <> n2.id AND 
    n1.SEASONCD = n2.SEASONCD AND 
    n1.ITEMCD = n2.ITEMCD AND
    n1.PRICETYPECD = n2.PRICETYPECD
GROUP BY id, SEASONCD, ITEMCD, PRICETYPECD, active_assignments
ORDER BY SEASONCD, ITEMCD, PRICETYPECD, active_assignments DESC, id;


Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Please learn to use ANSI JOIN rather than cross products.

I added sample data and a desired result, and agree it makes the question more clear. Sorry about that.

Explain in details why the rows with marker.id values 4 and 6 are excluded in the desired output. For example, the value 4 is absent in seat_marker at all, hence it cannot be defined as "most frequently referenced"

I was actually adding that explanation as you were posting this!

In your result table, you're saying id 1 removed because it's duplicate of id 2. Similarly id: 2 is duplicate of id 3. So, how id 3 show in your result table... @uPaymeiFixit Please simplify your question

According to your input data this is actual data of your table ... https://i.sstatic.net/gYWUWaVI.png where row 1, 2, 3 data are same (foo-bar-baz), row 4, 5 are same (qux-bar-baz) and row 6 is no duplicate (spam-eggs-ham)

once markerid 1 is removed then surely 2 and 3 fall into rule 2 and one of them should be randomly dropped?

The expected result included in your question appears to be incorrect. It should be displaying 4 instead of 5, as 5 has one corresponding row in seat_marker and is therefor the "row with the most occurrences".
One way to do this is with COUNT and ROW_NUMBER():
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT m.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SEASONCD, ITEMCD, PRICETYPECD ORDER BY COUNT(sm.id) DESC, m.id) AS rn
    FROM marker m
    LEFT JOIN seat_marker sm ON m.id = sm.MARKER_ID
    GROUP BY m.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn > 1;

Output:



id
SEASONCD
ITEMCD
PRICETYPECD
rn




2
foo
bar
baz
2


3
foo
bar
baz
3


4
qux
bar
baz
2



Here's a db<>fiddle.

Sorry about that, I spent so long yesterday looking at this issue that I'm making mistakes left and right. I changed the sample data and expected output data to hopefully fix everything.

This solution looks promising, but unfortunately I'm using MySQL 5.7, so I cannot use common table expressions. Is there an easy way to transform this to not use WITH?

The CTE can easily be replaced with a derived table but that won't help you as MySQL < 8 also lacks window functions. You could achieve the same with user variables but upgrading is a better option, as 5.7 is no longer supported.

Believe me, I would love to upgrade to 8 if I could. I'm not able to test your solution other than on db<>fiddle, but it seems to be correct so I will mark it as solved.

Here's a 5.7 compatible solution using user variables db<>fiddle
